# String Comparison, Java

Tags: java, string

```
class Compare
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String S1 = "Daniel";
        String S2 = "DANIEL";
        String S3 = "Daniel";
        String S4 = "daniel";

        System.out.println(S1.equals(S2));
        System.out.println(S1.equals(S3));
        System.out.print(S4.equalsIgnoreCase(S2));
    }
}
```

and the output is:
false
true
false
When it ignores the case, it should be "true"... right? o.O

Comment: It prints `false` `true` `true` for me.

Comment: No. `System.out.print(S4.equalsIgnoreCase(S2));
` yiels True:http://ideone.com/xyIJd

Comment: The above gives false/true/true

Comment: It prints `false
true
true` for me. @PaulBellora Snap!

Comment: I can't reproduce this even after setting the default locale to Turkey...

Comment: @JonSkeet: How come you got 3 upvote on your answer, which is completely irrelevant to question?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should, and it does for me. Here is the output I get from your exact program:

```
false
true
true
```

My guess is that you've either copied/pasted something wrong, or you're being fooled by your IDE (as suggested in one of the comments).

Comment: No. Check this :( 
https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/392391_3126359776627_1492372790_n.jpg

Comment: (Note that I've deleted my answer as I can't reproduce this having set the default locale to Turkey.)

Comment: Your snapshot does not correspond to your program. Your last print is not a println and yet there is a line return before the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" line. You are running another code. Are you running it with SHIFT+F6 in netbeans?

Comment: @DanielVictor What I'm saying is that on your snapshot, there should not be a line return before "BUILD". So my guess is that you are running some code in a different class or project.

Comment: Okay... I used just "F6" and when I use "Shift + F6" it worked... What is the difference... I don't know... Please say. And thanks! :)

Comment: @DanielVictor F6 runs your main project, using the current configuration which points to a specific class with a Main. SHIFT+F6 runs the main in the active window.

Comment: I must have used CMD to compile and run... :P

Comment: I removed the locale part in my answer, as equalsIgnoreCase isn't effected by the current locale, only the toUpperCase/toLowerCase methods are.

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld equalsIgnoreCase does call Character#toUpperCase